# Bluetooth Shield V2.2 for arduino

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, uuid, arduino-uno

I recently bought a bluetooth shield for my arduino. I am going to make an iOS app that will control the servos that I will be connecting to the arduino.

I feel stupid asking this because it is hard to find but where do I find the UUID for the bluetooth shield. I need to be able to talk to the arduino through the bluetooth shield? It must be easy because it is hard to find but I may be overthinking it.

Where do I find the UUID for a Bluetooth Shield for an arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try to "scan" available Arduino board with BLE Shield - for example here is an existing iOS app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ble-arduino/id547628998?mt=8

2) check your device's documentations

3) try those UUID's https://github.com/michaelkroll/BLE-Shield/blob/master/firmware/BLE-Shield-v2.0.0/BLE-Shield_gatt.xml